# Search the word From PDF in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

All

i am working on pdf search function using this link https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten for single page search this code will work correctly but when move to multiple

page search function after scrolling the page it's not pass CGPDFDocumentRef for second page

and page will pass null value for second page

How to search in whole pdf and page list should retrun  …???

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following  sample .

https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit